# C# delegate to notify changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

How can I notify an outside "source" of the changes I make using a delegate.

Basically I have a form, I fill in that form and click a button that saves 
my filled in data into a DB table as an XML. I want to be able to notify that the changes to the form have been made using a delegate that another "entity" can invoke.

```
public void Changes_Made()
{
     //yay. Changes made.
}

protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    //save data
    //...
    Changes_Made();
}
```

Practical scenario is: as i save my preferences, the grid that shows my data will refresh and use the preferences set when i click the ok_button. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise a event for notifying the changes.

```
public ctor() // Method where you want to hook the event, can be constructor or any thing else
{
    //Hook to event
    obj.ChangesMade += Changes_Made; 
    // Here obj is the object of type in which you have okButton_Click 
    // and ChangesMade event declaration

}
public void Changes_Made()
{
     //yay. Changes made. update grid
}


//declare event
public event EventHandler ChangesMade();
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    //save data
    //...

    //raise event
    if(ChangesMade != null)
        ChangesMade(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's what [C# events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the grid, and the save button are on the same page. If that's the case, simply call `PopulateGridData();`, or something like that directly after you saved the changes.

Comment: I don't have any access to the grid. I just want to notify that i have changed the preferences and that the grid should be displayed according to those changes.

Comment: they are not on the same page. they are on different assemblies. I can only set the preferences(which columns should be displayed, nr of rows pe page, etc)

Comment: Then I don't get something: you are using ASP.NET. If the grid is not on the same page, but you saved your data, than the grid will display the updated information next time someone reloads it. Or you want to tell already loaded grids in other users's browsers to reload with new data? If the later is what you want, the solution is more javascript than C#. Check out [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).